# Codeigniter query top store by price and and field by today

Tags: codeigniter

I am the beginner of codeigniter.
I have a query like this, I want to use this query in codeigniter
I would like to get top store_name by total_price

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id| store_name |  quality    | total_price |     time            |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1 | store_a    |     2       |   300       | 2019-06-19 08:20:57 | 
| 2 | store_b    |     1       |   100       | 2019-06-20 08:30:57 |
| 3 | store_c    |     4       |   50        | 2019-06-20 08:33:57 |
| 4 | store_b    |     2       |   300       | 2019-06-20 08:35:57 |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I have try

```
$this->db->select('store_name, SUM(total_price) AS  t_price', false);
$this->db->group_by('store_name');
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);

return $query->result();
```

i need output by date time today

```
    +------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
    | store_name |  quality    | total_price |     time            |
    +------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
    | store_b    |     3       |   400       | 2019-06-20 08:30:57 |
    | store_c    |     4       |   50        | 2019-06-20 08:33:57 |
```

Update
work for me

```
    $date = new DateTime("now");
    $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d ');

    $this->db->select('store_name, SUM(total_price) AS  total_price ,SUM(quality) AS    quality', false);
    $this->db->group_by('store_name');
    $this->db->where('DATE(time)',$curr_date);
    $this->db->order_by('total_price', "DESC");
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);


    return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
$curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d ');

$this->db->select('store_name, SUM(total_price) AS  total_price ,SUM(quality) AS    quality', false);
$this->db->where('DATE(time)',$curr_date);
$this->db->group_by('store_name');
$this->db->order_by('total_price', "DESC");
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);


return $query->result();
```

It will helpfull to you.

Comment: In above my answer, it is difference between where and group by clause interchange.